# Не хочет работать стандартный роутинг на index.php. В чём причина?

Tags: php, apache

Есть папка web. В папке два файла:
index.php в котором прописаны все последующие роутинги и .htaccess
Содержимое .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

При запросе "/web/" всё ок. Отображается index.php
При запросе "/web/*" т.е. что угодно после web/ получаю 404 т.е. такое чувство будто .htaccess не хочет отрабатывать и перенаправлять на index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в кофниге апача.

1. Проверяем включен ли mod_rewrite в апаче.

```
    apachectl -M (проверить есть ли в модулях rewrite_module)
    sudo a2enmod rewrite - включаем модуль 
    sudo systemctl restart apache2 - перезагружаем апач
```

2. В файле /etc/apache2/apache.conf важна строка AllowOverride All, она должна быть в таком виде, как это описано ниже.

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

После этого все запросы действительно стали лететь к index.php

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

В дополнению к ответу ниже - чтоб сделать корневой `web`:

1. В корень сайта файл htaccess:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ /web/$1
   ```
2. В папку `web`  файл htaccess:

   ```
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . index.php
   ```

Comment: Вы хоть немного понимаете регулярные выражения ?)) может я конечно чего то не знаю и реализация в апаче по одной только точке понимает сколько должно быть символов... "RewriteRule . index.php" по идее означает что только 1 символ с строки запроса перекидывать на индекс (потому и ставят или звездочку или плюс) и то я не уверен как оно отработает...

Comment: @noname2019 1 символ будет когда `^.$`. данное же выражение подойдет любой строке. так что увы и ах, в регулярных выражениях вы и сами не сильны

Comment: @teran то что Вы написали это означает начало и конец строки с одним символом кроме переноса строк, а где же повторения точки ? или в апаче это продумано ? видать увы и ах)))

Comment: @noname2019 вы не путайте маски захвата и целом валидность регулярки.  В эту маску попадет лишь одна буква, но выражение все равно будет истинно, и правило выполнится.

Comment: @teran скажите пожалуйста что такое маска захвата ? или киньте ссылку почитать (очень интересно) встретил на вики только такое "Объявляет «отмеченное подвыражение» (иногда называется «захват»), которое может быть использовано позже" и то это не про этот контекст

Comment: @noname2019 имелась в виду группа захвата. Мы  не разбираем ссылку регулярками, мы лишь проверяем удовлетворяет ли она им. В этом контексте не важно, напишите ли вы `.*` или просто `.`. если входящая ссылка будет `qwe`, то первое выражение даст результат `qwe` а второе `q`. Но суть в том, что оба из них дают результат, то есть правило выполняется.

Comment: mod_rewrite действительно был выключен - включил. 2. В конфиге апача было AllowOverride None для <Directory /var/www/>. Исправил на AllowOverride All. Помогло. Теперь все запросы идут к index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Первым делом нужно проверить включен ли mod_rewrite и то что вы заходите при запросе /web/ на индекс означает что директива DocumentRoot в настройках виртуального хоста не верно настроена (Вам нужно добавить в конце этого пути web что бы попадать сразу внутрь папки).

Или же если так и задумано что бы на web не ссылался DocumentRoot то Вам нужно сделать ещё один htaccess на одну директорию выше, положить рядом с папкой web и написать что то такое :

```
RewriteRule ^$ web/     [L]
RewriteRule (.*) web/$1 [L]
```

Если Вы поправили DocumentRoot то нужно :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: 1. mod_rewrite действительно был выключен - включил.                                 2. В конфиге апача было AllowOverride None для <Directory /var/www/>. Исправил на AllowOverride All. Помогло. Теперь все запросы идут к index.php.